# Tortoise SVN Setting up Server and Client Environment

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

New to Tortoise SVN Source Safe Repository.

I have ASP.Net web application which i like to set a Server Source Safe environment and couple of client environments ( office and my home ).

Do i need to install seperately for Sever and Client Source Safe ?

Comment: What is this "Source Safe" stuff?

Comment: Instead of using Visual Source Safe, I decided to go with Tortoise SVN

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886535/trying-to-set-up-tortoise-svn-newbie-question

Comment: @Chok see Frank's answer - you are confused.

Comment: Okay, i agree i am confused. I am familiar with Visual Source Safe. But my IT Department wants us to move to Open SourceSafe Repository. I preferred Subversion.

Comment: @Chok "Source Safe" is a product! There ain't no such thing as "Open Source Safe". The generic term for what SVN, git, Mercurial (and I suppose Source Safe) do is "version control".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think there is a bit of confusion on how the subversion ecosystem is organised today.

### Subversion vs TortoiseSvn

When people talk about Subversion they usually mean the server and client parts which you can find at http://subversion.apache.org/. This is where the source code of the project is available. They provide links to [binary builds](http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html).

TortoiseSvn on the other hand is a Windows only client tool which permits you to perform Subversion commands from windows explorer. You can find this tool at http://tortoisesvn.net/

### Setting up your own server

To set up a Subversion server on windows there are a number of options available. The easiest option and most performing, but not always the most accessible is by using the [svnserve](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html) service which is provided in the binaries of http://subversion.apache.org/.

The "standard" alternative is using a combination of the [apache webserver](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html) and the mod_dav_svn module. This permits access to the subversion repositories over http (and https)

Both solutions are sometimes hard to set up and a number of free and paying solutions exist to easier serve your subversion repositories on windows. Some examples, but definitely not an exhaustive list:

- [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/) **UNDER ACTIVE DEVELOPMENT**
- [SublimeSvn](http://www.sublimesvn.com/) **DISCOUNTINUED**
- [RocketSvn](http://www.axosoft.com/rocketsvn) **LINK LEADS TO SOME IRRELEVANT SITE**

Comment: @FilipDeVos, i agree with you. I am in a confused stage. I need an Open SourceSafe Repository which will act as Server Repository and Client Depository. Clients can be at my home or at my work. Server will be at our Main Office.

Comment: use TortoiseSvn on your client machine. http://tortoisesvn.net/support.html has a good guide. On the server install VisualSvn and expose it on the web over https. You can read some more here. http://www.visualsvn.com/server/getting-started/. You can ask specific questions as new questions on this site.

Comment: So for all Client Machines, i should install TortoiseSVN and for Server, i need to to install Visual SVN. Visual SVN Standard Edition is free, so i am glad about it. B

Comment: Basically all Client Tortoise SVN will talk to one common Server : Visual SVN !!

Comment: Indeed. There exist a large number of other clients if TortoiseSvn is not liked. (There is a long list on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Subversion_clients )

Comment: Thank you @Filip, I dont want to get confused further !! I will stick with TortoiseSVN for clients and VisualSVN for Server. Thank you for your comments

Answer (score 4):

I think you got several things mixed up:
- Visual Source Safe (or VSS) was a version control system by Microsoft (deprecated, and utterly broken IMO)
- Subversion (or SVN) is a widely used version control system (having a client-server architecture, but you can run both on the same machine)
- TortoiseSVN is a Windows client for SVN (having nice features like Integration into Windows explorer with icon overlays)

So if you want to start using SVN, you have to set up a server (should be pretty straightforward, since there's lots of good documentation available) and decide on a client (TortoiseSVN highly recommended if you are using Windows).

Comment: VSS is utterly broken in MS's opinion as well.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed ToirtoiseSvn comes with svnserve, which is pretty much all you need to run an SVN service if you don't need the visual bling or https:)